# javascript dynamic structure with array or object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, dynamic

Im trying to create a structure with Javascript as follows:

```
var users = {
    user.id: {
      session.id1: session.id1,
      session.id2: session.id2,
      session.id3: session.id3
    },
    user.id2: {
      session.id1: session.id1,
      session.id2: session.id2,
      session.id3: session.id3
    },
  };
```

What i need: add new sessions and remove them, removing okay, but how should i define object and how can i push new sessions to user obejct? That's why key is equal to value.

Comment: `user.id` cannot be used due to the `.`. `"user.id"` would work though, wrap it up in quotes.

Comment: or just use `user{ id: { id1: ... , id2: ... } }` and `id2:{ id1:..., id2: ... } }`. You can then adress them as `user.id.id1` or `user.id2.id1`

Comment: I think its better to create a class and then store this object in a users var

Comment: and `push()` is not available with objects, only with arrays

Comment: wrapping "user.id" in quotes don't take it as value from "user" object and displays it as text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first create an empty object and fill it as and when the data comes like

```
users[user.id] = {};
```

For an example:

```
var users = {};
var user = {id : 1}; //Data received(Just an example)
users[user.id] = {};
var session = {id1 : 1.1}; //Data received
users[user.id][session.id1] = session.id1;
console.log(JSON.stringify(users));
```

Comment: The code im using:

`if(!users[user.user_id]) {
          users[user.user_id] = {};
        }
        users[user.user_id][socket.id] = socket.id;`

Thanks! You helped a lot!

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use `session.id1` instead of something like `sessionId1` :

Assign value:

```
users['user.id'].['session.id1'] = value;
```

Create object:

```
var users = {
    'user.id': {
      'session.id1': session.id1,
      'session.id2': session.id2,
      'session.id3': session.id3
    },
    'user.id2': {
      'session.id1': session.id1,
      'session.id2': session.id2,
      'session.id3': session.id3
    },
  };
```

But I don't recommend it. If you are the only one who is gonna work with this code, it's ok.

Comment: session.id comes from socket.io in nodejs, also from object. And i would like to use the value in it as my key and also as a value.

Answer (score 0):

How about refactoring the user object to store sessions as an array and push, pop and slice them as required.

```
var users = [
   {
      id:'userid',
      sessions: [
          {
              id: 'sessionid',
              sessiondata: something
          },
          {
              id: 'sessionid',
              sessiondata: something
          }
      ]
 }];
```

This way to can just use normal array operators on the session array for each user.

Comment: What do you mean? Can you please provide some code? Thanks!